# Launch activity on Boot completed and another activity on Mount completion

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

This my Androidmanifest.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.testapp"
  android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="Pm61" >
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

   <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true"   android:largeHeap="true">

       <activity android:name="com.abc.testapp.MainClass" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
          <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
           </activity>

             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
            <activity android:name="com.abc.testapp.BootLoad"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
          </activity>

          <activity android:name="com.abc.testapp.Rxmain"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:launchMode="singleTask">
         </activity> 

         <receiver  android:name="com.abc.testapp.MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
          <intent-filter android:priority="500">
                <action android:name= "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action       android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/> 
                <data android:scheme="file" /> 
          </intent-filter>
         </receiver>

    </application>  

  </manifest>
```

This is my MyReceiver class for broadcasting

```
      package com.abc.testapp;

 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
  {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
       {
String action = intent.getAction();

  if(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(action))
    {
      Log.d("MYReceiver","Mounting Successfull");
      Intent serviceActivity = new Intent(context, Rxmain.class);
      serviceActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(serviceActivity); 
    }

  if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action))
  {
      Log.d("MYReceiver","Boot Successfull");
      Intent serviceActivity = new Intent(context, BootLoad.class);
      serviceActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(serviceActivity); 
  }
  }
}
```

My device is stand alone device, only my app will come on boot.

I want when boot complete it shall launch BootLoad activity and after MEDIA_MOUNTED it  should  launch Rxmain Activity.

But my bootLoad activity is not coming

So I have some doubts in this:

1. It is working sometimes but sometimes not?

2.what is this Priority in Intent-filter?

1. what this  data scheme does?
2. what I am doing is correct or not?

please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you've defined the intent filter for the broadcast receiver. This is your definition:

```
<receiver  android:name="com.abc.testapp.MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="500">
          <action android:name= "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
          <action       android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/> 
          <data android:scheme="file" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You've defined a single intent filter that will be triggered if the ACTION is either `BOOT_COMPLETED` or `MEDIA_MOUNTED`. But, by specifying the `<data>` tag, you will only receive broadcast Intents that have **data with scheme=file**.

The `BOOT_COMPLETED` Intent doesn't have any data, so your receiver won't get it.

You need to specify 2 separate intent filters, like this:

```
<receiver  android:name="com.abc.testapp.MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="500">
          <action android:name= "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:priority="500">
          <action       android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/> 
          <data android:scheme="file" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, its working but I am facing another problem Rxmain Class Activity is getting called twice. how to avoidthis

Comment: Why is it getting called twice? What broadcast Intents are you seeing? Add some logging or look in the logcat

Comment: onreceiver Mounting Successfull is getting called twice.How to prevent Rxmain.java class again even though I am getting two MEDIA_MOUNTED  event.Next  time it should  not come within if condition of MEDIA_MOUNTED.

Comment: Well, maybe you need to keep track of the fact that you already processed the MEDIA_MOUNTED event in a shared preference. Then, the next time it comes, you can check and see if you have already processed this. I'm not sure exactly what your application requirements are though.

Comment: Ya  Something like this ,  I am new in Android. Can you please  give me some sample code or edit my question.

Comment: My requirement: when BootCompleted event comes Load BootLoad activity and when MEDIA_MOUNTED event comes Load Rxmain Activity. but problem is my Rxmain activity is getting called twice. I want to stop this. Because when it is getting called twice some problem is coming.

Comment: Look in the logcat to see why that event is coming twice. Also, try declaring Rxmain Activity with `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest. This should prevent a second instance of the activity being created if there is already one running.

Comment: I don't mind answering your questions, but I'm not going to write your code for you (unless you want to pay me).